# USB Debugging

Tags: debugging, hardware, usb

I'm looking for a very specific USB device for debugging systems that may use USB but not with a regular computer (proprietary hardware). I want a device that has a USB host controller and two USB device connections. The device to be debugged is connected to the USB host controller and one of the device connections is connected to another device with it's own host controller on it. The the other device connection is connected to a pc. The point being that all USB data travelling through the device (from the device connected to the host controller to the device connected to the first device connection) is reported to the pc.

I'll happily write software to do the logging (in fact I want to) but I can't seem to find a board like this anywhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: Would it not possible to connect the device to a PC and use a driver on the PC to dump all traffic?

Answer (score 3):

I have an Ellisys USB analyser, which isn't exactly what you describe internally, but does sit between a peripheral and a host and use a separate PC to collect the data.

(i.e. it has two 'B' and one 'A' connectors on it.)

Excellent product, and very helpful company.

Answer (score 2):

Sniffing the USB shouldn't be too hard if you have the right hardware.  And that is the tricky question.  I haven't seen anything that describes the USB breakout box that you want.  However I can say that this is in the realm of the following two magazines:

1. [Nuts and Volts](http://www.nutsvolts.com)
2. [Circuit Cellar](http://www.circuitcellar.com)

If they don't have a USB breakout box project in their archives, then at least they will have advertisements for small cheap single board computers that would have multiple USB ports that you can use for buffering the signals and reporting it back to your PC.

Alternatively is it possible to just wire your PC up to the middle of your two devices and write a custom drive that echos data back and forth while sniffing off a stream for you?

Comment: Cool, thanks, I'll check out both those magazines and my local magazines which are bound to have similar things. It's possible to wire up the pc I would need a bit of extra hardware but I was thinking about making something that was usable by a greater crowd than just me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the long delay in my reply -- I checked out one of our USB developer's toolchain, and he uses a [Beagle USB Sniffer](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?module=Freaks%20Tools&func=viewItem&item_id=913). He seems happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a USB device with two upstream outputs.  I think according to the USB spec, this is not possible.  You will have two USB hosts trying to send messages and control the USB devices at the same time.

What if you were to look for a device which allowed you to view the data going through a hub via something other than a usb output?

If you're building something custom, take a look at this [USB chip site](http://ftdichip.com/). The chips are programmable via a windows application. Once you define how you want it to operate, it's saved on an EPROM on the dev board ($30-$50).

Sorry if this isn't helpful!